# Al Tarbeh Sicha Im Haisha- including Text Messaging?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty

The Mishna in Pirkei Avot says "Al Tarbeh Sicha Im Haisha", do not converse excessively with a woman.

Does this apply to text messages as well?

Comment: Interesting question. It appears the concern is one of creating an environment of inappropriate behaviors. If so, then how would texting be different than email, phone, letters, etc. which would all seem to fall under this rubric?

Comment: Maybe more distance and thus a less chashah of arayos?

Comment: I believe the Mishnah says it is also because of bitul zman so that would be true here too

Comment: @Mefaresh "Be'ishto amru" arayos isn't the concern here. Ergo, distance isn't a factor. (A=>B, -B=>-A)

Comment: True good point.

Comment: @Isaac but it is a practical benefit. See in context Nedarim 20a ואל תרבה שיחה עם האשה שסופך לבא לידי ניאוף.

Comment: @user6591 "Sof" doesn't mean immediately, it means eventually - the emotional intimacy created between the two parties will ***at some point*** lead to inappropriate action. See: Ben Sorrer - "niddun al shem sofo." If it said "shemeivi liday ni'uf," then it would imply a direct and immediate causation between sicha and ni'uf.

Comment: @Isaac I didn't imply otherwise. I don't think Mefaresh meant it was an emediate result of a single word spoken either.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76392/

Answer (score 13):

Avos DeRabbi Nasan ([7:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%96)) defines the problem as bringing home gossip to your wife, how you were treated negatively, how you treated others in response, etc.

According to that, the medium of communication - speaking, writing, in person or at a distance - seems irrelevant.

Comment: Nice answer - you beat me to it ;-) I love reading A.R.N.

Comment: A.D.N. also says ואל תרבה שיחה עם האישה ואפילו היא אשתו. ואין צריך לומר באשת חברו. שכל זמן שאדם מרבה שיחה עם האישה גורם רעה לעצמו, ובוטל מדברי תורה, וסופו יורש גיהנם:

Comment: But the underlying question is if we consider texting the same as Shmoozing. I don't think it is the same. Don't we lament how people lost their social life to social sites?

Comment: @HaLeiVi, I think that all depends on context. I'm sure Rechilus and Loshon Hara apply to texting.

Comment: @GershonGold, isn't that just rephrasing the Mishna? I'm not sure what your point is?

Comment: Lashon Hara and Rechilos is about conveying information. Schmoozing is something else. Texting may or may not be included, but it is definitely not equal. The Gemara says that we are to refrain from an extra word, which is hard to imagine applying to texting.

Comment: @HaLeiVi, The case of Avos DeRabbi Nasan is also about the effects of conveying the information.

Comment: Not with anyone. Obviously it is based on a certain type of conversation, which might or might not happen with text. And I'm inclined to think it doesn't.

Comment: @yishai please help me understand " כיון ששמע חברו אמר, אוי לי, דברים שבינו לביני הלך ושחן לאשתו."

Comment: @hazoriz, when his friend hears about it he will say "woe is me, things that were between him and me, he went and told his wife."

Answer (score 2):

The reason for not engaging in excessive conversation with a woman is explicitly stated in that mishnah, it brings to Bittul Torah (neglecting Torah study) therefore whether it is done through texting, phone call, etc., as long as it takes precious time which could have been dedicated to Torah study it is included in this Mishnah's horaah (teaching).

The full text of this Mishnah in Pirkei Avot (Ethics of the Father's) reads:
5. Yossei the son of Yochanan of Jerusalem would say: Let your home be wide open, and let the poor be members of your household. And do not engage in excessive conversation with a woman. This is said even regarding one's own wife—how much more so regarding the wife of another. Hence, the sages said: One who excessively converses with a woman causes evil to himself, neglects the study of Torah, and, in the end, inherits purgatory.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a moment to look at our [tour] so you can get a feel for how this site works, as it might be different from some you’re used to. Could you possibly [edit] your post to flesh out how this directly answers the question at hand, if texting is included in this ban?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See in particular the focus on sources. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The text of the Mishna doesn't seem to support the claim that *bittul Torah* is *the* reason for the advice. It looks like one of three potential consequences of men's excessive chatter with women. In addition, if the chief concern is the simple displacement of Torah study time by chatter time, not only the medium of chatter shouldn't matter, but also the gender of the interlocutor. Rather, it seems that the Sages' chief concern is likely something more inherent to chatter between a man and a woman, in particular, one potential consequence of which is neglect of Torah study.